# How to remove a word from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I want to know how to remove a specific word from a database in asp.net with c#. For example in the database there is a string that equals "hello,something,google,andetc,", I want to remove the word "something" how to do that?

this is my code for connecting to database:

```
public void RemoveTag(string tag)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("What should be here", con);

        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: From whole database ? or a table, or a column in a table, or a particular record ? what exactly you need ?

Comment: @Habib from a column, Let's say the tablename is 'text' and column name is 'column1']

Comment: What database are you using? SQL?

Comment: First off, it's really bad database relational design to store comma-delimited strings in text, you really should have a row for each value.  Also, just look at `REPLACE()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This primitive statement would get you what you want:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'something', '')
```

but it won't get rid of that comma. However, getting rid of the comma is going to be a bit trickier if it's not consistent. Let's say it were consistent, you could do this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, ',something', '')
```

or this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'something,', '')
```

but if it weren't consistent you'd probably want to do something like execute *two or three covering statements:*

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, ',something', '')
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'something,', '')
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'something', '')
```